# Maximum value of a function with iterated logarithms

Tags: tag-removed

Consider this function $f(x)=-x\log\log(bx)+x\log\log\log(bx)+ax$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants, and the logarithms are 2-based.

Is it possible to find the maximum value (or even with approximation) of $f(x)$, in terms of $a$ and $b$, for $x>\frac{16}{b}$?

Note, it can be shown that $f(x)$ is concave for $x>\frac{16}{b}$.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you call that maximum value $M(a,b)$,  you can first of all get rid of $b$ since $ M(a,b)= M (a,1) / b  $. And $ M(a,1) = g ^ \star (a) $, the [Legendre transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of the convex function $g(x):= x\log \log x -x\log\log\log  x$ for $x \ge 16$, and $g=\infty$ for $x <  16 $. Then, you may at least estimate $g ^ \star $ integrating $(g^\star)'=(g')^{-1}$. Note that you may also consider the somehow more natural definition of $g$ with finiteness domain $]2,\infty[$, which seems still convex.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. However, I think to find the inverse mapping $(g^')^{-1}$ is even harder.